# JQuery colorear celdas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, function, mouse

¿Como puedo hacer con JQuery para que al pasar el ratón por encima de las casillas (li) se muestren en rojo una a una y no todas a la vez? Al salir, ha de quitarse el color. En esto no hay problema, pongo captura de lo que hace al pasar el ratón por encima. Tampoco entiendo como hacer, si pulso una casilla, en el div con id=”info” (por ejemplo en la primera casilla) que aparezca el texto:

"Has hecho click en la casilla 1-1"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#div1 ul li").css("backgroundColor", "red");
    $("#div1 ul li").css("color", "white");
  }); 

  $("#div1").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#div1 ul li").css("backgroundColor", "white");
    $("#div1 ul li").css("color", "black");
  });

  $("#info").click(function(){
    /*$("#div1 ul li").*/
  });

});
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;}#div1{margin:1em;}#div1 ul{list-style-type: none;}
#div1 li{width:10%;float:left;}
#div1 li p {
  text-align:center;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #555;
}

#info{
  text-align:center; 
  font-size: 2em;
  padding:1em;clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<ul>
  <li><p>1-1</p></li>
  <li><p>1-2</p></li>
  <li><p>1-3</p></li>
  <li><p>1-4</p></li>
  <li><p>1-5</p></li>
  <li><p>1-6</p></li><li>
  <p>1-7</p></li><li>
  <p>1-8</p></li>
  <li><p>1-9</p></li>
  <li><p>1-10</p></li>
  <li><p>2-1</p></li><li>
  <p>2-2</p></li>
  <li><p>2-3</p></li>
  <li><p>2-4</p></li>
  <li><p>2-5</p></li>
  <li><p>2-6</p></li>
  <li><p>2-7</p></li>
  <li><p>2-8</p></li>
  <li><p>2-9</p></li>
  <li><p>2-10</p></li>
  <li><p>3-1</p></li>
  <li><p>3-2</p></li>
  <li><p>3-3</p></li>
  <li><p>3-4</p></li>
  <li><p>3-5</p></li>
  <li><p>3-6</p></li>
  <li><p>3-7</p></li>
  <li><p>3-8</p></li>
  <li><p>3-9</p></li>
  <li><p>3-10</p></li>
  <li><p>4-1</p></li>
  <li><p>4-2</p></li>
  <li><p>4-3</p></li>
  <li><p>4-4</p></li>
  <li><p>4-5</p></li>
  <li><p>4-6</p></li>
  <li><p>4-7</p></li>
  <li><p>4-8</p></li>
  <li><p>4-9</p></li>
  <li><p>4-10</p></li>
  <li><p>5-1</p></li>
  <li><p>5-2</p></li>
  <li><p>5-3</p></li><li><p>5-4</p></li><li><p>5-5</p></li>
  <li><p>5-6</p></li><li><p>5-7</p></li><li><p>5-8</p></li><li><p>5-9</p></li><li><p>5-10</p></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente, lo que tienes que haces es asignar los eventos a los `li` y no al `div` que los contiene, luego de esto podrás acceder a todas las propiedades del `li` al cual se le dio clic usando `this` dentro del selector, así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div1 ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
    $(this).css("color", "white");
  }); 

  $("#div1 ul li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "white");
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  });

  $("#div1 ul li").click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).text();
    
    console.log('Ha hecho clic en la casilla ' + texto);
  });

});
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;}#div1{margin:1em;}#div1 ul{list-style-type: none;}
#div1 li{width:10%;float:left;}
#div1 li p {
  text-align:center;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #555;
}

#info{
  text-align:center; 
  font-size: 2em;
  padding:1em;clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<ul>
  <li><p>1-1</p></li>
  <li><p>1-2</p></li>
  <li><p>1-3</p></li>
  <li><p>1-4</p></li>
  <li><p>1-5</p></li>
  <li><p>1-6</p></li><li>
  <p>1-7</p></li><li>
  <p>1-8</p></li>
  <li><p>1-9</p></li>
  <li><p>1-10</p></li>
  <li><p>2-1</p></li><li>
  <p>2-2</p></li>
  <li><p>2-3</p></li>
  <li><p>2-4</p></li>
  <li><p>2-5</p></li>
  <li><p>2-6</p></li>
  <li><p>2-7</p></li>
  <li><p>2-8</p></li>
  <li><p>2-9</p></li>
  <li><p>2-10</p></li>
  <li><p>3-1</p></li>
  <li><p>3-2</p></li>
  <li><p>3-3</p></li>
  <li><p>3-4</p></li>
  <li><p>3-5</p></li>
  <li><p>3-6</p></li>
  <li><p>3-7</p></li>
  <li><p>3-8</p></li>
  <li><p>3-9</p></li>
  <li><p>3-10</p></li>
  <li><p>4-1</p></li>
  <li><p>4-2</p></li>
  <li><p>4-3</p></li>
  <li><p>4-4</p></li>
  <li><p>4-5</p></li>
  <li><p>4-6</p></li>
  <li><p>4-7</p></li>
  <li><p>4-8</p></li>
  <li><p>4-9</p></li>
  <li><p>4-10</p></li>
  <li><p>5-1</p></li>
  <li><p>5-2</p></li>
  <li><p>5-3</p></li><li><p>5-4</p></li><li><p>5-5</p></li>
  <li><p>5-6</p></li><li><p>5-7</p></li><li><p>5-8</p></li><li><p>5-9</p></li><li><p>5-10</p></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No te hace falta usar Javascript para colorear la celda por la que pasas el ratón. Con el uso de la pseudo-clase `:hover` de **CSS** puedes hacerlo. Lo bueno de hacerselo por **CSS** es que él solito se ocupa de detectar cuando entra y sale el ratón y de volver a su estado original. Te ahorras el programar un `mouseenter` y un `mouseleave` y además manejas los estilos desde **CSS** directamente.

En cuanto al tema de informar de  la celda que se ha seleccionado debes hacer el uso del `this`, que en el caso de los eventos, hace referencia al elemento del **DOM** que disparó el evento.

Para ello, enlacé un evento `onclick` a los `<li>` de tu **HTML** que pertenezcan al div `div1` y gracias al `this` recuperar el contenido del `<p>` hijo del `<li>` al que se la ha hecho `click`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div1 li").click(function(){
    var celda = $(this).find('p').text();
    $('#info').html('<p>Has pulsado la celda ' + celda + '</p>');
  });

});
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;}#div1{margin:1em;}#div1 ul{list-style-type: none;}
#div1 li{width:10%;float:left;}

#div1 li:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#div1 li p {
  text-align:center;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #555;
}

#info{
  text-align:center; 
  font-size: 2em;
  padding:1em;clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<ul>
  <li><p>1-1</p></li>
  <li><p>1-2</p></li>
  <li><p>1-3</p></li>
  <li><p>1-4</p></li>
  <li><p>1-5</p></li>
  <li><p>1-6</p></li><li>
  <p>1-7</p></li><li>
  <p>1-8</p></li>
  <li><p>1-9</p></li>
  <li><p>1-10</p></li>
  <li><p>2-1</p></li><li>
  <p>2-2</p></li>
  <li><p>2-3</p></li>
  <li><p>2-4</p></li>
  <li><p>2-5</p></li>
  <li><p>2-6</p></li>
  <li><p>2-7</p></li>
  <li><p>2-8</p></li>
  <li><p>2-9</p></li>
  <li><p>2-10</p></li>
  <li><p>3-1</p></li>
  <li><p>3-2</p></li>
  <li><p>3-3</p></li>
  <li><p>3-4</p></li>
  <li><p>3-5</p></li>
  <li><p>3-6</p></li>
  <li><p>3-7</p></li>
  <li><p>3-8</p></li>
  <li><p>3-9</p></li>
  <li><p>3-10</p></li>
  <li><p>4-1</p></li>
  <li><p>4-2</p></li>
  <li><p>4-3</p></li>
  <li><p>4-4</p></li>
  <li><p>4-5</p></li>
  <li><p>4-6</p></li>
  <li><p>4-7</p></li>
  <li><p>4-8</p></li>
  <li><p>4-9</p></li>
  <li><p>4-10</p></li>
  <li><p>5-1</p></li>
  <li><p>5-2</p></li>
  <li><p>5-3</p></li><li><p>5-4</p></li><li><p>5-5</p></li>
  <li><p>5-6</p></li><li><p>5-7</p></li><li><p>5-8</p></li><li><p>5-9</p></li><li><p>5-10</p></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```